# Scrolling in widgets in Android 2.x with android-support-v4.jar?

Tags: android, android-support-library

As I can see, more and more functions from Android 4.x like fragments or action bar are now supported on lower android versions by using support library. Anyone knows, if it works also for scrolling inside widget, which was introduced in Android 3.x? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not going to happen, and probably not really possible. This needs support for the corresponding `RemoteView`'s, etc. which is a little deeper in the platform than fragments, etc. You are, of course, welcome to give it a try.